# Is Mongo DB better than Mysql DB for notification storage and retrieval?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, express

I had a mobile app backend written by someone else in node(express). He is managing all data in mysql DB but storing notification for new cutomer signup etc in mongodb is there a performance gain or I should use one d.b throughout the project?

Comment: You should add some parameters around what is "better" for you for this project, or this question will probably be voted to close.

Comment: Added parameter for comparison actually I have both mysql and mongo integrated in same project and I want to use one (mysql) if there is no special performance gain in using mongodb for manging notification storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB is good for handling large unstructured data. The best thing about MongoDB is that it is not bound to schema design.

To store notification you can use MongoDB though notifications can be in billions or trillions in number. So, MongoDB could be the choice to store and retrieve that data. Data retrieve is faster in MongoDB if we compare MySql.

Checkout the link [MongoDB v/s MySql](https://dzone.com/articles/comparing-mongodb-amp-mysql)

Comment: "The best thing about MongoDB is that it is not bound to schema design" - its arguable whether that is a good thing. One of the reasons for the popularity of MongoDB is that it suports indexing of attributes other than the document key - which requires at least a partial schema.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is highly organized for its flexibility, high performance, reliable data protection, and ease of managing data. Proper data indexing can resolve your issue with performance, facilitate interaction and ensure robustness.

But if your data is not structured and complex to handle, or if predefining your schema is not coming easy for you, you should better opt for MongoDB. What’s more, if you're required to handle a large volume of data and store it as documents, MongoDB will help you a lot!

The result: One isn’t necessarily better than the other. MongoDB and MySQL both serve in different niches.

[Reference](https://dzone.com/articles/comparing-mongodb-amp-mysql)